# Using eval(parse()) construction within dplyr

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) with two columns named: Peter_Smith and Peter_Dow

```
df <- as_data_frame(matrix(ncol=2, nrow=2))
namesDF <- c("Peter_Smith", "Peter_Dow" )
names(df) <- namesDF
```

I want to get, for example, first column using:

```
library('dplyr')
target <- "Smith"
df1 <- select(df, eval(parse(text=paste0('Peter_', target)))
```

And get the next ERROR:

```
Error in eval(parse(text = paste0("Peter_", target))) : 
object 'Peter_Smith' not found
```

Why?

I use R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11) -- "Great Truth"

Comment: `eval("Peter_Smith")` is searching for the object.

Comment: Where is `select` from? With `dplyr`, you're looking for `quasiquotation`.

Comment: and how to search a column?

Comment: @NelsonGon yes, dplyr

Comment: `df[, paste0("Peter_", target)]`

Comment: Or if you want to be more explicit, try `df[, grepl("^Peter_", names(df))]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `select(df, !!paste0('Peter_', target))`

Comment: it works. can you explain how?

Comment: Please read `?quasiquotation`

Answer (score 0):

```
target <- "Smith"
target <- enquo(target)
df1 <- select(df, paste0('Peter_', !!target))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks. but Sonny was first, your answer is correct too